# Cart promotion not found message in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to change message which a customer received when he send wrong promotion code like

> "Promotion with code test777 not found!"

Below is full resp from Shopware but I can't find where I can do it. I changed this message in snippets but it didn't help. I tried to find it in database but again nothing was found.

```
{
"promotion-not-found": {
    "promotionCode": "test777",
    "message": "Promotion with code test777 not found!",
    "code": 0,
    "key": "promotion-not-found",
    "level": 20,
    "messageKey": "promotion-not-found"
}
```

}

Comment: ok. Looks like it's connected to Headless store because default store shop has new snippet text

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [plugin that adds translations](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-translations). In your snippet json files you can then overwrite existing translations.

To overwrite the one you are looking for:

```json
{
  "checkout": {
    "promotion-not-found": "Promotion with code \"%code%\" could not be found."
  }
}
```

You can also change the translation by using the administration web-interface. Navigate to [Settings > Snippets](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/snippets), select the of translations, search for `checkout.promotion-not-found` and change the value there.

Comment: the problem is with administration web-interface. I've changed it via Settings > Snippets and it doesn't work also I clear cache but nothing helped. Also I've checked database and there changes were implemented but my headless front receive old value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation, you could also consider providing the specific error messages on the client side.

In order to do that, you can use the `error.key` field to map an error to your custom message snippet. If there's no snippet present, you could fall back on `error.message`.